# run java applications on tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

how can we run java applications on apache tomcat server? i have tried editing the xml file and also tried making a war file and placing it in tomcats webapp dir.

the methods test and test 2 are methods from a simple java application i made.
I have the following class

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {
    RemoteEV3 ev3;
    static RMIRegulatedMotor motorA;

    static boolean stop=false;

    @Path("{f}")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response DeployRobot(@PathParam("f") String f) throws JSONException, NotBoundException, IOException {
        String r="run";
        if(f.equals(r)) {
            test();
        } else {    
            test2();
        }

        return Response.status(200).entity("").build();
    }

    public static void test() throws IOException, IOException, NotBoundException {

        RemoteEV3 ev3=new RemoteEV3("10.0.1.1");
        ev3.isLocal();

        // Open Ports
        ev3.getPort("A");

        //create motors

        if(motorA==null){motorA=ev3.createRegulatedMotor("A", 'L');}

        //move motors, grab,suppress
        while (!stop){
            motorA.forward();
            grab();
            motorA.stop(true);
            Sound.twoBeeps();
            stop=true;
            System.out.println("Robot is moving!");
        }

        if (stop){
            motorA.close();
        }
    }

    public static void test2(){
        System.out.println("|***                           Move Robot                                   ****|");
    }

    public static void grab(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is it jersey Restful service?

Comment: Yes i have used Jersy as my framework

Answer (score 0):

To run applications on Apache tomcat u can go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager
```

and manage your webapps, deploying them adding your .war file